# How to use "Session" in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, session

Is there a similar functionality in jQuery as `Session["Param"]` in C#? How can I use it?

I've searched `"sessionStorage"` in jQuery, but I can't understand.

Comment: No need for jQuery, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you said, you can use **`sessionStorage`** in **`JavaScript`**.

▶ You can set a new parameter like so:

```
sessionStorage.param1 = "Hello";
/* Or */
sessionStorage.setItem("param1", "Hello");
```

▶ Then, you can get it as follows:

```
var param = sessionStorage.param1;
/* Or */
var param = sessionStorage.getItem("param1");

console.log(param); /* It'll output `Hello`. */
```

---

**Notes:**

▶ Using **`sessionStorage`**, **you can only store data for one session**, which means everything will be deleted if you close the specific browser tab. If you want to **permanently store data** use **`localStorage`** instead.

▶ As you are apparently very new to JavaScript, I suggest you take a look at the following documentation about **`Web Storage`** in **`JavaScript`**:

- Mozilla Development Network ([sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage), [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage))
- W3 Schools ([both](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp))

Answer (score 1):

```
// ${FEEDBACK_QUESTION_IDS} this is session attribute name in controller

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        window.questionIdsList = [];
        var i = 0;
        <c:forEach items="${FEEDBACK_QUESTION_IDS}" var="queId">
        questionIdsList[i] = parseInt(${queId});
        i++;
        </c:forEach>

    });
</script>
```

Finally we can use  `window.questionIdsList` as same as array

Answer (score 1):

The following can be used to store and retrieve data in the following ways:

To store:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("error", 'some value');
```

To retrieve:

```
sessionStorage.getItem("error");
```

Answer (score 0):

To use session data ,you don't need jquery you can use setItem ,getItem and removeItem to deal with the session data which is stored as a json object and accessible via key.